# Freeze Pane Bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010.  Say I freeze pane on row 2.  I scroll the bottom pane down to row 50, then I enter a value in a cell above row 2 and press enter, the bottom pane resets and scrolls back up.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: As I recall, that is the way Excel has always functioned - going back to the late 90's.  The way around it is to use the mouse cursor to select a cell in row 50.

Comment: I only have excel 2010 so don't know if it happens in 2007 or not.  I thought it did..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` instead of `Freeze Panes`. The `Split` feature works a lot like the freeze panes feature, except that the separators are thicker. You can access it right next to the Freeze Panes button:

[image]

And the bottom part of the screen doesn't move up if you insert a value on row 2 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What's more, you can manually adjust the position of the separator without having to remove the split, select an appropriate cell and insert the split again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a bug/feature with panes, but rather the behavior of the enter key.  i.e. when you hit enter, it positions in the next cell down--when that next cell is in the bottom pane, it has to reposition.   You can test this by making changes with enter in row 1, when the pane is between 2 & 3.

So, some work arounds:

1. Don't press enter, use the checkbox instead
2. Change the behavior of enter to move left/right/up instead of down.
3. insert a row height=1 row below your intended upper pane row (and move pane below this new row), so that enter positions you inside the upper pane, and not the lower.